# Beginning Programmer having trouble linking JavaScript to case Statement?

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginning programmer who is having difficulty with this code and would appreciate any feedback or help.  The purpose of this code was to create an Major Adviser that could calculate what school is best to be placed into. My issue with this coding is that the Submit button is not connecting and the case statement is not connecting. Please give me any suggestions and any feedback on what you think I can do to get this to work correctly. Thank you for your help.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Major Adviser</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type=text/javascript>

function Calculate(a, b, c, d) {

var C = 0;
var SB = 0;
var S = 0;
var M = 0;
var SM = 0;
var LA = 0;
var GP = 0; 

function a(){
switch (document.ZF.elements.Hobbies)
  {
  case value=="Math":
    S + 2;
    SM + 3;
    LA + 1;
    break;
  case value=="Science":
    C + 2;
    SB + 2;
    M + 2;
    LA + 1;
    GP + 2;
    break;
  case value=="Computer Club":
SM + 1;
    C + 1;
    SB + 1;
    M + 2;
    LA + 2;
    GP + 1;
    break;
  case value=="Television Club":
    SM + 1;
    C + 1;
    SB + 1;
    M + 2;
    LA + 2;
    GP + 1;
    break;
  case value=="Community Service":
    SM + 1;
    C + 1;
    SB + 1;
    M + 2;
    LA + 2;
    GP + 1;
    break;
  case value=="Music":
    SM + 1;
    C + 1;
    SB + 1;
    M + 2;
    LA + 2;
    GP + 1;
    break;
case value=="Environmentalist":
    SM + 1;
    C + 1;
    SB + 1;
    M + 2;
    LA + 2;
    GP + 1;
break;
case value=="Acting":
    SM + 1;
    C + 1;
    SB + 1;
    M + 2;
    LA + 2;
    GP + 1;
break;
default:
    document.writeln("not working");
    }
}

function b(){

    switch (document.ZF.elements.Subject);
  {
  case value=="Math":
    S + 2;
    SM + 3;
    LA + 1;
    break;
  case value=="Science":
        C + 2;
        SB + 2;
       M + 2;
         LA + 1;
        GP + 2;
    break;
  case value=="Social Studies":
        SM + 1;
        C + 1;
        SB + 1;
        M + 2;
        LA + 2;
        GP + 1;
    break;
  case value=="English":
        SM + 1;
        C + 1;
        SB + 1;
        M + 2;
        LA + 2;
        GP + 1;
    break;
  case value=="Computers":
        SM + 1;
        C + 1;
        SB + 1;
        M + 2;
        LA + 2;
        GP + 1;
    break;
  case value=="Art":
        SM + 1;
        C + 1;
        SB + 1;
        M + 2;
        LA + 2;
        GP + 1;
    break;
default:
    document.writeln("not working");
    }
}

function c(){

switch (document.ZF.elements.type_of_person);
  {
  case value=="Introvert":
        S + 2;
        SM + 3;
        LA + 1;
    break;
  case value=="Extrovert":
        C + 2;
        SB + 2;
        M + 2;
        LA + 1;
        GP + 2;
    break;
  case value=="Both":
        SM + 1;
        C + 1;
        SB + 1;
        M + 2;
        LA + 2;
        GP + 1;
    break;
default:
    document.writeln("not working");
        }
}

function d(){

document.writeln("School of Communication and Arts: " + C);
document.writeln("School of Social and Behavioural Science: " + SB);
document.writeln("School of Science: " + S);
document.writeln("School of Science and Mathematics: " + SM);
document.writln("School of Management: " + M);
document.writln("School of Liberal Arts: " + LA);
document.writln("School of Global and Professional Programs: " + GP);

    }
    }
    </script>

<h1 align="right"><img src="Marist_College_2_220374.JPG" width="15%" height="15%" alt="Marist Logo"> <img src="poughkeepsie1.JPG" width="45%" height="15%" alt="Poughkeepsie"/> <img src="Marist_College_2_220374.JPG" width="15%" height="15%"       alt="Marist Logo"/>
</h1>

<h3 style="text-align:center">Marist Major Advisor</h3>
<form name="ZF">
First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" size = 25 maxlength = 15> <br>
<br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname" size = 25 maxlength = 15> <br>
<br>
<p>What kind of Personality are you?</p>
<input type="radio" name="type_of_person" value="Introvert">Introvert<br>
<input type="radio" name="type_of_person" value="Extrovert">Extrovert<br>
<input type="radio" name="type_of_person" value="Both">Both<br>
<input type="radio" name="type_of_person" value="None">None<br>
<p>What are your best subjects/activities?</p>
<input type="checkbox" name="Subject" value="Math">Math<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Subject" value="Science">Science<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Subject" value="Social Studies">Social Studies<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Subject" value="English">English<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Subject" value="Computers">Computers<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Subject" value="Art">Art<br>
<p>What activities or hobbies are you involved in?</p>
<input type="checkbox" name="Hobbies" value="Math">None<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Hobbies" value="Science">Sports<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Hobbies" value="Computer Club">Computer Club<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Hobbies" value="Television Club">Television Club<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Hobbies" value="Community Service">Community Service<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Hobbies" value="Music">Music<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Hobbies" value="Environmentalist">Environmentalist<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Hobbies" value="Acting">Drama Class/Acting<br>
<p>How long are you willing to be in college for?</p>
<select>
    <option value="blank"></option>
    <option value="Don't Mind">Don't mind the amount of time.</option>
    <option value="2Year">2 years Associates Degree</option>
    <option value="4Year">4 years Bachelors Degree</option>
    <option value="4+">4+ Masters Degree</option>
    <option value="Doctrine">Doctrine</option>
</select><br>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="Calculate()"/>
<input type="reset"Value="Clear">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your case statement syntax is incorrect

Comment: you need to assign values using `C = C + 1`, otherwise `C + 1;` is not very different than `0 + 0;` (code will execute but nothing will really happen or matter)

Comment: Don't forget to add `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the beginning of whole thing.

Comment: What is the thing supposed to do?

Comment: [Here's a working example to get you started](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20366592/390897). I don't typically do this, but it looks like you've just started dabbling with JS. ;D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are new to programming there are several things I need to point out.

There are syntax errors that you could catch if you open any modern browser and access the developer tools.  For example if you are in Firefox just right click and select `Inspect Element with Firebug`.  That will get you started on your own.

So here are the fixes:

- You need the `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the beginning.
- All of the assignments need to be changed from `S + 2;` to `S += 2;`. Otherwise you would need to do something like `S = S +2;`
- As stated you can remove the `value ==` from the case statements.
- Also as stated you have `writln` instead of `writeln`.
- There are several semicolons at the end of switch statements that can't be there. For example `switch (document.ZF.elements.Subject);`
- For the Submit button I change the `type="button"` to `type="submit"` removed the `onclick` in place of a jQuery `.submit()` event.
- The switch statements weren't taking the `value` and they would only look at the first selected.  So that needed a `for` loop to pull out the `checked` values and pass them into the switch functions 1 at a time.

I also clean up the formatting and syntax structure in this copy of it and added a bit of jQuery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Major Adviser</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type=text/javascript>
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        var C,SB,S,M,SM,LA,GP;

        $("#ZF").submit(function() {
            C = 0;
            SB = 0;
            S = 0;
            M = 0;
            SM = 0;
            LA = 0;
            GP = 0;

            var hobbies = $('.hobbies');
            for(var i = 0; i < hobbies.length; i++) {
              if (hobbies[i].checked) {
                var hobby;
                hobby = hobbies[i].value;
                a(hobby);
              }
            }

            var subjects = $('.subjects');
            for(var i = 0; i < subjects.length; i++) {
              if (subjects[i].checked) {
                var subject;
                subject = subjects[i].value;
                b(subject);
              }
            }

            c();
            d();
        });

        var a = function(hobby) {
            switch (hobby) {
            case "Math":
                S += 2;
                SM += 3;
                LA += 1;
                break;
            case "Science":
                C += 2;
                SB += 2;
                M += 2;
                LA += 1;
                GP += 2;
                break;
            case "Computer Club":
                SM += 1;
                C += 1;
                SB += 1;
                M += 2;
                LA += 2;
                GP += 1;
                break;
            case "Television Club":
                SM += 1;
                C += 1;
                SB += 1;
                M += 2;
                LA += 2;
                GP += 1;
                break;
            case "Community Service":
                SM += 1;
                C += 1;
                SB += 1;
                M += 2;
                LA += 2;
                GP += 1;
                break;
            case "Music":
                SM += 1;
                C += 1;
                SB += 1;
                M += 2;
                LA += 2;
                GP += 1;
                break;
            case "Environmentalist":
                SM += 1;
                C += 1;
                SB += 1;
                M += 2;
                LA += 2;
                GP += 1;
                break;
            case "Acting":
                SM += 1;
                C += 1;
                SB += 1;
                M += 2;
                LA += 2;
                GP += 1;
                break;
            default:
                document.writeln("not working");
            }
        };

        var b = function(subject) {
            switch (subject) {
            case "Math":
                S += 2;
                SM += 3;
                LA += 1;
                break;
            case "Science":
                C += 2;
                SB += 2;
                M += 2;
                LA += 1;
                GP += 2;
                break;
            case "Social Studies":
                SM += 1;
                C += 1;
                SB += 1;
                M += 2;
                LA += 2;
                GP += 1;
                break;
            case "English":
                SM += 1;
                C += 1;
                SB += 1;
                M += 2;
                LA += 2;
                GP += 1;
                break;
            case "Computers":
                SM += 1;
                C += 1;
                SB += 1;
                M += 2;
                LA += 2;
                GP += 1;
                break;
            case "Art":
                SM += 1;
                C += 1;
                SB += 1;
                M += 2;
                LA += 2;
                GP += 1;
                break;
            default:
                document.writeln("not working");
            }
        };

        var c=  function() {

            switch ($('.type_of_person').val()) {
            case "Introvert":
                S += 2;
                SM += 3;
                LA += 1;
                break;
            case "Extrovert":
                C += 2;
                SB += 2;
                M += 2;
                LA += 1;
                GP += 2;
                break;
            case "Both":
                SM += 1;
                C += 1;
                SB += 1;
                M += 2;
                LA += 2;
                GP += 1;
                break;
            default:
                document.writeln("not working");
            }
        };

        var d=  function() {

            document.writeln("School of Communication and Arts: " + C);
            document.writeln("School of Social and Behavioural Science: " + SB);
            document.writeln("School of Science: " + S);
            document.writeln("School of Science and Mathematics: " + SM);
            document.writeln("School of Management: " + M);
            document.writeln("School of Liberal Arts: " + LA);
            document.writeln("School of Global and Professional Programs: " + GP);

        };
    });
    </script>

    <h1 align="right">
        <img src="Marist_College_2_220374.JPG" width="15%" height="15%" alt="Marist Logo"> 
        <img src="poughkeepsie1.JPG" width="45%" height="15%" alt="Poughkeepsie" /> 
        <img src="Marist_College_2_220374.JPG" width="15%" height="15%" alt="Marist Logo" />
    </h1>

    <h3 style="text-align: center">Marist Major Advisor</h3>
    <form name="ZF" id="ZF">
        First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" size=25 maxlength=15>
        <br> <br> 
        Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname" size=25 maxlength=15> 
        <br> <br>
        <p>What kind of Personality are you?</p>
        <input type="radio" name="type_of_person" class="type_of_person" value="Introvert">Introvert<br>
        <input type="radio" name="type_of_person" class="type_of_person" value="Extrovert">Extrovert<br>
        <input type="radio" name="type_of_person" class="type_of_person" value="Both">Both<br>
        <input type="radio" name="type_of_person" class="type_of_person" value="None">None<br>
        <div id='subject-div'>
            <p>What are your best subjects/activities?</p>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Subject" class="subjects" value="Math">Math<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Subject" class="subjects" value="Science">Science<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Subject" class="subjects" value="Social Studies">Social Studies<br> 
            <input type="checkbox" name="Subject" class="subjects" value="English">English<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Subject" class="subjects" value="Computers">Computers<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Subject" class="subjects" value="Art">Art<br>
        </div>
        <div id='hobbies-div'>
            <p>What activities or hobbies are you involved in?</p>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Hobbies" class="hobbies" value="Math">Math<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Hobbies" class="hobbies" value="Science">Science<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Hobbies" class="hobbies" value="Computer Club">Computer Club<br> 
            <input type="checkbox" name="Hobbies" class="hobbies" value="Television Club">Television Club<br> 
            <input type="checkbox" name="Hobbies" class="hobbies" value="Community Service">Community Service<br> 
            <input type="checkbox" name="Hobbies" class="hobbies" value="Music">Music<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Hobbies" class="hobbies" value="Environmentalist">Environmentalist<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Hobbies" class="hobbies" value="Acting">Drama Class/Acting<br>
        </div>
        <p>How long are you willing to be in college for?</p>
        <select>
            <option value="blank"></option>
            <option value="Don't Mind">Don't mind the amount of time.</option>
            <option value="2Year">2 years Associates Degree</option>
            <option value="4Year">4 years Bachelors Degree</option>
            <option value="4+">4+ Masters Degree</option>
            <option value="Doctrine">Doctrine</option>
        </select><br> <br> 
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/> 
        <input type="reset" Value="Clear">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually, changing the button to a submit button is unnecessary. The `onclick` event will work just fine. And as a nitpicky matter, you should probably avoid it (except for actual submissions of course) since submit buttons have a special significance.

Comment: agree with Vidya, maybe some browsers will even trigger warnings about resending the form when refresh/back history

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of bad things goin' on:

- Your case statements should read like `case "Math":`
- No semicolons at the end of your `switch` lines.
- Your increments should read `S += 2` or `SM += 3`
- You've spelled `writeln` wrong a few times.
- Given how you are using your variables like `C`, `SB`, etc., they should be global.
- Functions are nested within `Calculate`. Remove all these inner functions.
- Your way of testing values isn't going to work. If you are on a modern browser, try `document.querySelector("[name=Subject]").value` and similar for the others.
- And this technically doesn't matter, but your variable names are atrocious. I mean that with kindness.

Comment: I think the variable names are sensible abbreviations of what they stand for.

Comment: I really hope you're right. Like more than anything. Those variable names bring tears to my eyes.

Comment: I'm more concerned that this program is supposed to advise users of suitable majors based on their perceived personality traits!

Comment: Fair point. Especially since JavaScript bugs could send the poor kids into the completely wrong lives.

Answer (score 1):

```
case value=="Computers":
```

should be:

```
case "Computers":
```

etc.
You don't need the `value==` part.

Also, you have typos in lines like this:

```
document.writln("School of Management: " + M); // writeln
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a working example to help you get started](http://jsbin.com/uKUWUmO/4/edit?html,js,output). Note that version has a few modifications that should make debugging a bit easier.

Here's what's causing your script to break:

- `case` statements don't use comparisons like `case value=="Math"`. The following is the proper format

  ```
  switch(n) {
    case 1:
      // execute code block
      break;
    case 2:
      // execute code block
      break;
    default:
      // code to execute if n is different from case 1 and 2
   }
  ```

  Aside from that, you haven't even defined `value` yet!  `value == 'Whatever'` throws a `ReferenceError`
- In order to increment the value of a variable you need to reassign the new value as follows:

  ```
  var x = 0;
  x + 1;     // `x` is still 1
  x = x + 2; // `x` is now 2
  x += 2;    // Shorthand for previous assignment; `x` is now 4
  x++;       // Even shorter-hand for `x += 1`; `x` is now 5
  ```

  So a statement like `S + 2;` will not change the value of `S`, you'll need to use one of the appropriate forms presented above (e.g. `S += 2`) to change the value of `S`
- You seem to have misunderstood how arguments (a.k.a. parameters) should be used. Your `Calculate` function doesn't actually require the arguments `a`, `b`, `c`, or `d`, and the subsequent methods you define (`function a()`, etc.) can't be run by passing the values in as parameters to `Calculate`. Just to clarify how arguments work, here's a quick review.  Much like with a mathematical function, values are passed to the JavaScript function to be used therein. Consider this simple `multiply` function:

  ```
  function multiply(x, y) {
    return x * y;
  }
  multiply(7, 3) // returns 21
  ```

  Here we sent two values to be used in the computation.
- If you still would like to keep each switch statement wrapped in a function, you'll need to call that function later. For example:

  ```
  function greet(name) {
    function sayHello() {
      console.log('Hello ' + name + '!');
    }
    function askQuestion() {
      console.log('How are you ' + name + '?');
    }
    sayHello();
    askQuest();
  }
  ```

  While JavaScript does allow nesting functions within functions, it should only be done judiciously, such as [when defining a class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#The_methods). This example doesn't quite qualify.
- `document.ZF.elements.Whatever` returns a `NodeList` object, rather than the value of the checked element. You'll need to specify an element in the list before extracting a value:
      var hobbies = document.ZF.elements.Hobbies;
      var hobby = hobbies[0].value
- If you want to accumulate the scores from multiple checkbox items, you'll need to iterate over all elements in the `NodeList` while passing them through a score calculation function.

  ```
  var hobbies = document.ZF.elements.Hobbies;
  for(var i = 0; i < hobbies.length; i++) {
    if (hobbies[i].checked) {
      var hobby;
      hobby = hobbies[i].value;
      calculateHobbyScore(hobby);
    }
  }
  ```
- You've misspelled `writeln` as `writln` a few times!
- You should embrace the JavaScript console in your browser. It'll help you catch errors in your code more easily.  You can access the JavaScript console in Chrome and Firefox with the keyboard shortcut `CTRL + Shift + J`

  [**Chrome Console**](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console)

  [image: Assertion failure example]

  [**Firefox Console**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console)

  [image]